# How to change pin voltage in quartus ii?

Tags: fpga, quartus

I'm trying to change pin voltage on 'Altera cyclone 4 FPGA' in **Quartus**? I have changed it in a pin planner and source voltage. But, unfortunately, the voltmeter always show '3 - 3.3 V'.

Am I missing something. Please, advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change pin voltages from Quartus.  The I/O voltage is equal to the voltage you supply at VCCIO (for that particular I/O bank).

The Quartus setting is to tell the design tools what voltage your hardware will be using so that timing and power consumption calculations will be correct.

As shown by this table in the device datasheet, the I/O Standard and VCCIO voltage level are linked, you cannot select an I/O standard at a different voltage without changing the I/O supply voltage your PCB provides to the FPGA VCCIO pins.

[image]

Comment: But when I change VCCIO in I/O bank properties it also doesn't help

Comment: @Kendra_T: Those properties are where you tell it what hardware changes you made.  Your PCB provides a voltage to the FPGA and you tell Quartus what voltage you gave it.  Quartus doesn't control the voltage, it does calculations and needs to know the voltage.

Comment: Thank you! That explained a lot of problems I had lately!